# SQL injection understanding trouble c#

Tags: c#, parameters, xampp, sql-injection

Recently I have been studying how to use parameters to store data from c# to xampp database. I just need a few clarification about some topics.

```
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

ConnectionClass cc = new ConnectionClass();

private MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionClass.GetConnection());
private MySqlCommand cmDB;

cc.SetCMD("UPDATE mia_payroll.tbl_attendance SET TimeIn = @TimeIn, Date = @Date, EID = @EID;");

using(myConn)   ** // 1) can I do it like this or instantiate another new MysqlConnection?**
{
   cmDB = new MySqlCommand(cc.GetCMD(), myConn);

   try
   {
      myConn.Open();
      myReader = cmDB.ExecuteReader(); 
      // 2)In MSDN it's SqlDataAdapter is mine okay?
      cmDB.Parameters.Add("@EID", Text, 11);
      // 3) is the position of this line correct or do I need to adjust this?
      // 4) the text in () generates error how do I do this?
      cmDB.Parameters["@EID"].Value = lblEID.Text;
      // 5) How do I instantiate another 5 variables? (an int, a text, a time, date and a varchar)
      // 6) and does parameters allow special characters into database? or should I just use regex?

      while (myReader.Read())
      {
         TimeSpan TIN = myReader.GetTimeSpan("TimeIn");
         lblTIN.Text = TIN.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

So school is not helping that much for they only taught us only the basic of C# and I have been watching Programming Knowledge from youtube and he doesn't have any vids on parameters.

Comment: Where are your questions?

Comment: @Teja I'm going to assume they're the ones embedded in the code. (Though Enriko really should put them in the body of the question itself.)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Comment: @JoeC i thought it was more practical to place them near the lines i'm having problem with but thanks for the notice

Comment: @MarkNg it was helpful but it only has 1 `parameter` how do i add if i have more than 1 `parameter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this sample, please edit accordingly to suit your needs accordingly.

```
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

var timeIn = blabla;
var eID = lblEID.Text;
//var blablabla = blablabla; 
var query = @"UPDATE mia_payroll.tbl_attendance SET TimeIn = @TimeIn, Date = @Date, EID = @EID"; //are you missing a WHERE clause? otherwise you will update all row. maybe you want to do something like below.
//var query = @"UPDATE mia_payroll.tbl_attendance SET TimeIn = @TimeIn, Date = @Date, EID = @EID WHERE rowID = @rowID";
using(MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionClass.GetConnection()))
using(MySqlCommand cmDB = new MySqlCommand(query, myConn))
{
    try
    {
        //for your question to me about adding parameters value, just keep adding.
        cmDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", timeIn);
        cmDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eID", eID);
        //cmDb.Parameters....... and so on
        //now execute query
        myConn.Open();
        using(MySqlDataReader myReader = cmDB.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                 //do what you want with your result.
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! i have been looking for a simple example for almost 2 weeks